# jQuery scroll exception

Tags: jquery, scroll

I just added a smooth scroll to my page, this was added to my navbar. The logo area I want to keep the scroll effect but I don't want the active class to be added to that section. 
Can anybody help with this, here is my code.

```
//HTML
<header>
        <nav class="navbar transparent navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a id="name-brand" class="navbar-brand" href="#big-image">Logo</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul id="nav-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a class="link-pad" href="#about">About</a></li>
                            <li><a class="link-pad" href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a class="link-pad" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

//JS
This is the jquery that I have, which will add active class to all the links in the navbar, but I am not able to figure out how to exclude the logo part.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 500, 'swing', function() {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event) {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#nav-menu a').each(function() {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#nav-menu ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        } else {
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}

function removeActive() {}
```

What I need is to keep the scroll effect when clicking on the logo area but I do not want the active class to be added.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the logo is enclosed inside of a link `<a>` tag so that is getting picked up by your jquery selector `$('#nav-menu a')`.

In order to prevent the **active** class from being added to the logo link, just add a unique `id="name-brand"` attribute into your logo `<a>` element.

The in your jquery you can add this to check if the element has the **logo_id** attribute that you gave it, and if so, don't add the **active** class to it:

```
function onScroll(event) {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#nav-menu a').each(function() {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#nav-menu ul li a').removeClass("active");

            // Add 'if' statement to prevent active class addition to logo
            if ( !currLink.is("#name-brand") ) {
                currLink.addClass("active");
            }

        } else {
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: when I add the "#logo_id" the css from the logo gets removed and it still adds the active class.

Comment: Oh I see now that the logo element already has an "id" attibute:  id="name-brand".  So you can just use that in the new "if" statement like this:  if ( !currLink.is("#name-brand") ) {
                currLink.addClass("active");
            }

Comment: I'll try it and se if that preventa the active class to activate thanks.